# Colocar palavras em maiusculo

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, front-end

Tenho um input e gostaria que quando o usuário digitasse as letras vão ficando em maiuscula pelo efeito do javascript. Sem o form eu consigo, mais quando coloco o form não funciona.

`

```
<ui:define name="content">  
<h:form id="frm">
    <p:outputLabel value="Cliente" for="cliente" />
    <p:inputText id="cliente" value="#{cadastroOrcamentoBean.orcamento.cliente}" />

</h:form>
</ui:define>`
```

`

```
$("#cliente").keyup(function(){
var start = this.selectionStart,
    end = this.selectionEnd;

$(this).val( $(this).val().toUpperCase() );
this.setSelectionRange(start, end);});
```

`

Comment: Porque pelo css não tem o efeito que o javascript faz da letra ficando em maiúscula.

Comment: Tá chamando o javascript, pq quando eu tiro o <h:form id="frm">..</h:form> funciona

Comment: Acredito que o problema é como colocar os ids aqui  $("#cliente")

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver. O seletor ficou como no código abaixo.

```
$("#frm\\:cliente").keyup(function(){

var start = this.selectionStart,
    end = this.selectionEnd;

$(this).val( $(this).val().toUpperCase() );
this.setSelectionRange(start, end);});
```